# Github pages: how to redirect error url to 404.html page with nojekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, custom-error-pages, static-pages

I have created simple static site on github pages.
The page https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site says that all error url-s should be redirected to 404.html page.
But the problem is that there is a .nojekyll file in my root folder. So, error url-s just shows "Error code: 404" and [www.example.com/404](http://www.example.com/404) shows my custom 404.html.
Is there a way to fix this issue?

about *.nojekyll*: I get hosting on github pages with 1st goal - to place there a google assets file with key by special url with the dot at the beginning of the folder name. This file should be accessible by robots without any redirection with the plain access. But without *.nojekyll* file a folder with the dot at the beginning is not visible ..

Answer (score 0):

Clarification needed: why do you need the *.nojekyll* file in the first place?

Comment: hi, @Nuno I explained this at the bottom of the question. I use this hosting as  free tool to place the file that Google ask me to place a file with a key by a special url that contain dot at the beginning. But Jekyll is not allow to see anyone the directories like this. So, I had to switch it off.
example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json